# insert data into two tables in php mysql only for data with checkbox checked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that need help

I have 2 table that need to be inserted

```
po

poID     poNo     prNo     branch     supplier    date_po     date_delivery note    tax    grandtotal
```

and the other is

```
detail_po
poNo      productCode     productName    qty    price    discount    total
```

my code for inserting data into two table doesn't work
for the detail data there are checkbox  in the form, and only data with checkbox checked will insert into detail_po table

it doesn't show any error message either

```
<?php
header("Location: poAdd.php");
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("a.karat");
if(isset($_POST['product_submit']))
{

$poNo           = $_POST['poNo'];   
$prNo           = $_POST['prNo'];   
$branch         = $_POST['branch'];
$supplier       = $_POST['supplier'];   
$date_po        = $_POST['date_po'];
$date_delivery  = $_POST['date_delivery'];
$note           = $_POST['note'];
$tax            = $_POST['tax'];
$grandtotal     = $_POST['grandtotal'];


$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO po (poNo,prNo,branch,supplier,date_po,date_delivery,note,tax,grandtotal)VALUES('$poNo', '$prNo','$branch', '$supplier', '$date_po',  '$date_delivery', '$note', '$tax','$grandtotal')");

$check=$_POST['check'];
foreach($check as $i)
{
    $prcode=$_POST['productCode'.$i];
    $prname=$_POST['productName'.$i];
    $qty=$_POST['qty'.$i];
    $price=$_POST['price'.$i];
    $discount=$_POST['discount'.$i];
    $total=$_POST['total'.$i];
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into detail_po (poNo,productCode,productName,qty,price,discount,total) value ('$pono', '$prcode', '$prname', '$qty', '$price','$discount','$total',)");
}
if($query)
{
?>
<script>
alert("success");
</script>
<?php
}
}
header("Location: poAdd.php");
?>
```

need help to make it works

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).